# Progress bar not updating during file upload to Azure Storage in Blazor

Tags: .net, blazor, azure-blob-storage, progress-bar

I am trying to implement a progress bar that updates in real time during file uploads to Azure Storage in a Blazor WebAssembly application. However, the progress bar only updates after the upload is complete, and does not show any progress during the upload. I have tried modifying my code, but the issue persists.

I have tried modifying the UpdateProgress method to set the progress bar value directly, instead of setting the fileProgressPercent and progressWidthStyle variables.
I have tried using a different approach to upload the file to Azure Storage, but the issue persists.

The progress bar should update in real time as the file is uploaded to Azure Storage, showing the percentage of the file that has been uploaded.

The progress bar does not update during the upload, and only shows the final value after the upload is complete.

Can anyone help me identify the issue with my code and suggest a solution to update the progress bar in real time during file uploads? Thank you in advance.

Here is my code:
UploadVideo.razor

```
@inject ILargeFileUpload largeFileUpload
<div class="row g-3">
    <div class="form-group col-sm-12 mt-3">
        <InputFile OnChange="OnInputFileChange" class="form-control" />
        <br />
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" type="button" @onclick="UploadFile">Upload</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        @{
            var progressCss = "progress" + (displayProgress ? "" : "d-none");
            progressWidthStyle = fileProgressPercent + "%";
        }
        <div class="@progressCss">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar"
                 style="width:@progressWidthStyle" aria-valuenow="@fileProgressPercent"
                 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            </div>
            <div>
                <br />
                <label>@labelText</label>
                <br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    private bool displayProgress;
    private int fileProgressPercent = 0;
    private string progressWidthStyle; 

    private IBrowserFile? file;

    private string labelText = "";

    private void OnInputFileChange(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        file = e.File;
    }

    private async Task UploadFile()
    {
        try
        {
            if (file is not null)
            {
                displayProgress = true;
                fileProgressPercent = 0;
                progressWidthStyle = "0%";

                
                await largeFileUpload.UploadFile(file, UpdateProgress);

                labelText = $"Upload of {file.Name} file successful";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            labelText = $"Upload Failed due to {ex.Message}";
        }
    }
    private void UpdateProgress(int progress)
    {
        fileProgressPercent = progress;
        progressWidthStyle = $"{fileProgressPercent}%";
    }
}
```

My LargeFileUpload.cs Service

```
{
    public interface ILargeFileUpload
    {
        Task UploadFile(IBrowserFile file, Action<int> onProgress);
        int GetFileProgressPercent();
    }
    [RequestSizeLimit(500 * 1024 * 1024)]
    public class LargeFileUpload : ILargeFileUpload
    {
        private IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        private readonly ILogger<LargeFileUpload> _logger;

        public LargeFileUpload(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment, ILogger<LargeFileUpload> logger)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
            _logger = logger;
        }
        private long maxFileSize = 500 * 1024 * 1024;
        private long totalBlocks;
        private long totalBytesUploaded;
        private int fileProgressPercentC = 0; 
        public async Task UploadFile(IBrowserFile file, Action<int> onProgress)
        {
            if (file is not null)
            {
                try
                {
                    //await largeFileUpload.UploadFile(file);
                    var connectionString = "#########";
                    var containerName = "#########";
                    var blobName = file.Name;

                    BlockBlobClient blockBlobClient = new BlockBlobClient(connectionString, containerName, blobName);

                    List<string> blockList = new List<string>();

                    var stream = file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize);
                    while (true)
                    {
                        byte[] b = new byte[4 * 1024 * 1024];
                        var n = await stream.ReadAsync(b, 0, b.Length);
                        if (n == 0) break;
                        string blockId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                        string base64BlockId = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(blockId));
                        await blockBlobClient.StageBlockAsync(base64BlockId, new MemoryStream(b, true));
                        blockList.Add(base64BlockId);

                        totalBytesUploaded += n;
                        fileProgressPercentC = (int)((totalBytesUploaded / (double)file.Size) * 100);

                        // call the progress callback method
                        onProgress(fileProgressPercentC);
                    }
                    await blockBlobClient.CommitBlockListAsync(blockList);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

        }
        public int GetFileProgressPercent()
        {
            return fileProgressPercentC;
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The issue in the code is that the UI is not being updated during the file upload process because the upload operation is blocking the UI thread.

The `UI thread` is busy in uploading the file and cannot update the `progress bar` until the upload is complete. To update the progress bar in real-time, you need to perform the **file upload operation on a separate thread**, so that the UI thread remains free to update the progress bar.

By using the `Task.Run` method to run the UploadFile method in a separate thread.

**UploadFile method using Task.Run**

```
private async Task UploadFile()
{
    try
    {
        if (file is not null)
        {
            displayProgress = true;
            fileProgressPercent = 0;
            progressWidthStyle = "0%";
                       
            await Task.Run(() => largeFileUpload.UploadFile(file, UpdateProgress));

            labelText = $"Upload of {file.Name} file successful";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        labelText = $"Upload Failed due to {ex.Message}";
    }
}
```

And you should also modify the `UpdateProgress` method to use the `InvokeAsync` method to update the UI from the separate thread.

**UpdateProgress**

```
private void UpdateProgress(int progress)
{
    fileProgressPercent = progress;
    progressWidthStyle = $"{fileProgressPercent}%";

    InvokeAsync(() =>
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    });
}
```

The `InvokeAsync` method queues a UI update request on the UI thread, which will be processed when the UI thread is free. The StateHasChanged method tells Blazor to update the UI with the latest state. By calling these methods from the separate thread, you can update the progress bar in real-time as the file is being uploaded.

Comment: [Polite]  You probably missed the "Blazor WebAssembly application", currently there's only one thread!

Answer (score 0):

As it's a not easy to simulate what you have, this is just a suggestion that might work.

The issue is that you are not yielding control at any point during the upload back to the UI thread, so there's no thread time to update the UI.  You have `await`s but I'm now sure that they are actually yielding.  You can't run the process on another thread as at present WASM is single threaded.

Try adding a `await Task.Delay(1)` after the callback.

```
totalBytesUploaded += n;
fileProgressPercentC = (int)((totalBytesUploaded / (double)file.Size) * 100);

// call the progress callback method
onProgress(fileProgressPercentC);
await Task.Delay(1);
```

In theory this should do a proper yield, but I reserve judgement before you test it!